# Storing a users access token in django view

Tags: python, django, shopify

I am tryig to store a shopify access token in a django view upon first installation/auth (before they create an account & connect to DB).

I am new to django so please be nice.

How do I store this access token for usage later on? Can it be stored in "session"? is it already?

Here's my [repo](https://github.com/aorzh/shopify_django_app) and python view:

```
def finalize(request):
    shop_url = request.GET['shop']
    auth_code = request.GET['code']
    hashed = request.GET['hmac']
    ts = request.GET['timestamp']
    print("shopURL", shop_url)

    print("success request")
    try:
        r = requests.post('https://'+shop_url+'/admin/oauth/access_token', data = {'client_id':'xx','client_secret':'xx','code':auth_code})

        print("request response > > > > ", r.json())
        this_response = r.json()
        print(this_response["access_token"],"this_response[access_token]")
       # >>>>>> STORE THIS TOKEN SOMEWHERE?
        request.session['shopify'] = {
            "shop_url": shop_url,
            "access_token": this_response["access_token"]
        }

    except Exception:
        messages.error(request, "Could not log in to Shopify store.")

        return redirect(reverse('shopify_app_login'))

    messages.info(request, "Logged in to shopify store.")

    response = redirect(_return_address(request))
    request.session.pop('return_to', None)
    return response
```

Comment: Do you want to store the access token across sessions or just for the current session?

Comment: across sessions.. but even when i revisit the site - i have to re-auth everytime.. somethings not working @kshikama

Answer (score 3):

Best options is to store this in Django user. You can extend the Django user to add your own fileds

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shopify_access_token = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

later you can access this token using `request.user.profile.shopify_access_token`